# Let M and N be normal subgroups of a group G such that $G = MN.$ Prove that $G/(M \cap N) \simeq G/M \times G/N$.

Tags: abstract-algebra, group-theory, proof-verification

Let M and N be normal subgroups of a group G such that $G = MN.$ Prove that $G/(M \cap N) \simeq G/M \times G/N$.

Claim 1: $M\cap N$ is a normal subgroup of G:

Proof:

1. $1_G \in M$ and $N$ since M and N are both subgroups.
2. For all $x, y \in M \cap N,$ $x, y \in M$. Since M and N are subgroups, $x, y \in N$ and $xy^{-1} \in M$ and $xy^{-1} \in N$. Therefore, $xy^{-1} \in M \cap N$.

Hence, $M\cap N$ is a normal subgroup of G.

Define $f: G \to G/M \times G/N$ by $f(g) = (gM, gN)$.

Claim 2: $f$ is an homomorphism.

Proof: For all $g, h \in G$, $f(gh) = (ghM, ghN) = (gMhM,gNhN) = (gM, hM)(gN,hN) =f(g)f(h)$. Hence, $f$ is a homomorphism. Note that $ghM = gMgM$ and $ghn = gNhN$ because $M$ and $N$ are normal.

Claim 3: $f$ is surjective.

Proof: Since $G = MN,$ for all $g \in G$, $g = mn$. For all $(xM,yM) \in G/M \times G/N$. We have $xM = (mnM) = n(n^{-1}mn)M = nM$. Similarly, $yN = m'n'N = m'N$. Hence, $f(m'n) = (m'nM,m'nN) = (n(n^{-1}m'n)M,m'N) = (xM,yM)$. Therefore, $f$ is surjective.

Using First Isomorphism Theorem, we get the result.

Comment: @DietrichBurde know that there is a solution out there but I just want to know how i can improve on my solution. I don't want to straight away get the answer

Comment: Yes, I understand, but the first answer given there shows how you can improve your solution, right ? By the way, $M$ and $N$ need not be finite subgroups (for CRT).

Comment: Hmmm....Why did you delete all your own work?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Let $M$ and $N$ be two normal subgroups of $G$. Show that $M \cap N$ is also normal in $G$. Then show that $G/(M \cap N) \cong (G/M) \times (G/N)$](http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/310351/let-m-and-n-be-two-normal-subgroups-of-g-show-that-m-cap-n-is-also-nor?lq=1)

Answer (score 1):

Your proof that $M \cap N$ is normal is not complete since you only show that $M \cap N$ is a subgroup. There are some typos in the proof that $f$ is a homomorphism.

It is a very good idea to use the Isomorphism Theorem, but for this you have to show that the kernel of $f$ is $M \cap N$. And then you can also omit the proof that $M \cap N$ is normal, because this follows from the general fact that kernels are normal.

Answer (score 0):

Assuming that you want a critique of your work, here are a couple of notes:

You claim to be showing $M\cap N$ is a *normal* subgroup of $G$, but the steps (1),(2) only establish that the intersection is a subgroup.  Showing normality needs a few more words.

The construction of the surjective homomorphism $f$ is sound, but you seem to have omitted the final ingredient for the First Homomorphism Thm., showing that the kernel of $f$ is $M\cap N$.