# If $G$ is a group and $a,b\in G$ and $e$ neutral element why $ab = aeb$?

Tags: group-theory

The Problem I have if this would be true then one could also say $aaa^{-1}b=ab$.

Why do I know that there don't exist counterexamples for which the inequality holds?

Comment: $aeb = a(eb) = ab$, and $aaa^{-1}b = a(aa^{-1})b = aeb = ab$.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Among the group axioms you also have associativity. That allowed you to write
$$aeb = a(eb) = ab $$
I assume by neutral you mean the identity. The inverse element axiom states that every element has an inverse with the property
$$xx^{-1} = x^{-1}x = e $$
Thus we can use associativity as follows
$$aaa^{-1}b  = a(aa^{-1})b = aeb = a(eb) = ab$$

Comment: The part of this proof:https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/310351/let-m-and-n-be-two-normal-subgroups-of-g-show-that-m-cap-n-is-also-nor where the first answer says and simillary we get $yM=n'M$ makes use of this. I was not sure if the proof requires this Transformation and whether the Transformation was correct

Answer (score 1):

If $e$ is neutral element then $$\forall x. ex =x $$
so $eb$ transforms into $b$ (because $eb = b$)

Answer (score 1):

$aaa^{-1}b = a(aa^{-1})b = aeb = (ae)b = ab$

So yes, you *CAN* say that, and you'd be one hundred percent correct when you *do* say that.

> Why do I know that there don't exist counterexamples for which the inequality holds?

The same way you know that there aren't any counter examples to $k\times \frac 1k =1$ when $k \ne 0$.

*BY DEFINITION* $aa^{-1} = e$ and BY DEFINITION $aeb = (ae)b = ab$.  So that is a PROOF.